# Range Locks in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I want to lock a region of memory in c++.

I have a circular buffer of memory. A producer thread writes into the buffer and a consumer thread reads from the buffer. The two processes only need to synchronize if they are accessing an overlapping region of memory.

Is there a class in the c++ standard library (or any library for that matter) that I can use to build a lock over a region of memory?

If not, what's a good approach to take here?

Comment: How this lock for region of memory is different than generic lock aka mutex?

Comment: Right - because it has range semantics. Basically, I want to have something like: lock(10, 50) in one thread and lock (40, 90) in another - the second should be block because 40 is within (10, 50).

Comment: I doubt any library would have it, most probably you would have to implement one by yourself possibly using `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but thought I'd check.

Comment: You could try std::atomic.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue, I would not consider std::mutex / std::condition_variable. This is the best i can think of:

Singleton with 2 members.

```
std::atomic<__uint128_t> write_range, read_range;
```

Then use them for write range 1000 to 1999 and read range 500 to 1499 like so:

```
singleton::instance()->write_range = (__uint128_t) 1999 << 64 | 1000;
singleton::instance()->read_range = (__uint128_t) 1499 << 64 | 500;
```

This should be the most efficient way of setting / comparing without locks. Detecting clashes:

```
bool clash(std::atomic<__uint128_t> const& w, std::atomic<__uint128_t> const& r) {
  return w >> 64 > r >> 64 && ((size_t)w <= (size_t)(r >> 64)) ;
}
```